# Interactive Exports from GIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mapinfo, visualisation

I'm looking for suggestions of interactive exports from GIS software. The need for this research is that many of our customers either do not have access to GIS or the knowledge to use it.

One method I have explored is the use of Interactive PDFs. But the set up of these is particularly difficult as the outputs contain a huge number of layers!

Do you know of any other exports which for example have points linked to table of data when clicked on?

Comment: If you edit your Question to describe any deficiencies you are finding with exported PDFs as the solution to your requirements it may help trigger thoughts on alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a several tools to export a GIS-map to an interactive HTML- or SVG-map. Here are some examples:

**[HTML ImageMapper](http://www.alta4.com/webmapping/html-imagemapper.html?L=1) (ArcGIS):** You can use the ArcGIS extension HTML ImageMapper to export your ArcGIS map to an interactive map. The output is a HTML-map. You only need a browser to view the map.
Here is a link to an [example map](http://www.transportscotland.gov.uk/road/technology/traffic-count/map-application).

**[Mappetizer](http://www.mappetizer.de/en/description/index.html) (ArcGIS):** Export to an interactive SVG-map.

**[SVGMapMaker](http://www.spatialinsights.com/catalog/product.aspx?product=154) (Mapinfo):** Export to an interactive SVG-map.

Comment: That looks really interesting, is there something similar for MapInfo as we use both platforms.

Comment: HTML ImageMapper does not work with Mapinfo. There are probably many similar tools like HTML ImageMapper. An other aproach is to Export SVG instead of HTML. [Mappetizer](http://www.mappetizer.de/en/description/index.html) (ArcGIS) and [SVGMapMaker](http://www.mappetizer.de/en/description/index.html) (Mapinfo) export to SVG (I have both not yet used.) I assume that there is no tool with works with ArcGIS _and_ Mapinfo.

Comment: Jens - The SVG idea looks brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use data interoperability for export data to others formats.
Or you can use the Fme Cloud Api for custom exportation ;)

Comment: I would love to have access to FME but the chance of it being deployed minimal. Thanks for the future idea though!

Comment: Fme Cloud 1$/hour